# Is there any way to reduce the brightness of specific laptop display pixels in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, display, lcd

My laptop's screen has  a couple of small bright spots. They are obnoxious but I don't want tobuy a new laptop or replace my current one's screen. I suspect that the bright spots could be fixed by reducing the brightness of the particular pixels (through software).

### Is there any way to reduce the brightness of specific pixels in Windows 7?

Or are there any other good approaches to fix bright spots or at least reduce their annoyingness?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might have some faulty pixels.

As the whole screen is lit by a single backlight, it is impossible to reduce the brightness of an individual pixel.

Depending on brand, make and time of purchase, your best bet is getting it replaced under warranty, though some manufacturers require a certain number of pixels to be dead before they register it as a manufacturing fault.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's all or nothing with things like that.

Are you 100% sure it is the screen and not your GPU? If you are sure, buy a new screen – it's not expensive and easily replaceable.

Answer (score 1):

If out of warranty and it really bugs you I can suggest using an ice pick wrapped in electrical tape. Press **gently** on the hot pixels and you can often make them go dark.

It does risk damage to the screen (obviously) but i have had good success with this method.